# Method isBeingPresented in iOS 4.*

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5

Method isBeingPresented is available for iOs 5.*
What analog method of isBeingPresented i can using for iOS 4.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it exists in iOS4: This method is about new form of presentation view controllers:

> In iOS 5.0 and later, custom UIViewController subclasses can now act
>   as container view controllers

so, in iOS4 you may use `viewDidAppear` method insteed. Just make your own boolean flag, and set it to true when view did appear.